# Netcdf averages time varable when averaging multiple .nc files

Tags: netcdf, netcdf4, nco, cdo-climate

I have averaged a bunch of hourly netCDF files (for one year) to create one large netCDF file that contains an average daily value. The time variable represents hours since 2005-1-1 00:00:00 and looks like this:

```
time = 11.5, 35.5, 59.5, 83.5, 107.5, 131.5, 155.5, 179.5, 203.5, 227.5...;
```

However, I would like the time variable to represent the beginning of the day so that it looks like this:

```
time = 0, 24, 48...;
```

Is there a way to manipulate the time variable so that it represents the beginning of the day instead of the middle of the day?

Thanks!

Comment: ps: Note that the relevant tag is "cdo-climate" for climate data operators :-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if this command may have solved my issue:

```
ncap2 -s "time=time-11.5" infile.nc -o outfile.nc
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use cdo to shift the time axis

```
cdo shifttime,-11.5hours infile.nc outfile.nc
```